# Get SMS message and Phone number and Transfer it to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have created the app that listens Sms and reply the Location (latitude, Longitude ) the Incoming mobile number. I created `SMSReceiver` class by Extending `BroadCastReceiver`.. Since it is not an `Activity`, i cant use `intent` to transfer the message to other activity to Read Location.

Any one can help me out to Receive sms by using `Intents` for the purpose of sending the Sms(string ) to another `Activity`. Hope you get my problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can start a service from your SMSReceiver -

```
intent.setClass(context, SmsReceiverService.class);
intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
SmsReceiverService.beginStartingService(context, intent);
```

Comment: My friend.. That sms Receiver is not inherited from Activity.. it extends BroadcastReceiver.. So i'm unable to use Intents

Comment: Check this link. Implement the onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver which accepts two parameters - context and intent. More info here -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)